# CakePHP 2.0.0 Can't login after I followed ACL Tutorial

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication, cakephp-2.0, acl

I followed the ACL tutorial provided by CakePHP [Simple Acl controlled Application](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/simple-acl-controlled-application/simple-acl-controlled-application.html) but I just encountered a problem. After I just finish the tutorial, I logged in but it just redirect me to login page. Please help. This is my AppController.

```
<?php 

class AppController extends Controller {
public $components = array(
    'Acl',
    'Auth' => array(
        'authorize' => array(
            'Actions' => array('actionPath' => 'controllers')
        )
    ),
    'Session'
);

public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form', 'Session');

public function beforeFilter() {
    //Configure AuthComponent
    $this->Auth->allow('display');
    $this->Auth->loginAction = array(
      'controller' => 'users',
      'action' => 'login'
    );
    $this->Auth->logoutRedirect = array(
      'controller' => 'users',
      'action' => 'login'
    );
    $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array(
      'controller' => 'posts',
      'action' => 'add'
    );
}
}
?>
```

And this is my UserController.php

```
<?php
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');
/**
 * Users Controller
*
* @property User $User
*/
class UsersController extends AppController {



public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->Auth->allow('initDB'); // We can remove this line after we're finished
}

public function initDB() {
    $group = $this->User->Group;

    // Allow admins to everything
    $group->id = 1;
    $this->Acl->allow($group, 'controllers');

    // allow managers to posts and widgets
    $group->id = 2;
    $this->Acl->deny($group, 'controllers');
    $this->Acl->allow($group, 'controllers/Attendees');
    $this->Acl->allow($group, 'controllers/Orders');


    // allow basic users to log out
    $this->Acl->allow($group, 'controllers/users/logout');
}
/**
 * index method
*
* @return void
*/
public function index() {
    $this->User->recursive = 0;
    $this->set('users', $this->paginate());
}
/**
* view method
*
* @param string $id
* @return void
*/
public function view($id = null) {
    $this->User->id = $id;
    if (!$this->User->exists()) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid user'));
    }
    $this->set('user', $this->User->read(null, $id));
}
/**
 * add method
*
* @return void
*/
public function add() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->User->create();
        if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user has been saved'));
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }
    $groups = $this->User->Group->find('list');
    $this->set(compact('groups'));
}
/**
* edit method
*
* @param string $id
* @return void
*/
public function edit($id = null) {
    $this->User->id = $id;
    if (!$this->User->exists()) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid user'));
    }
    if ($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) {
        if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user has been saved'));
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    } else {
        $this->request->data = $this->User->read(null, $id);
    }
    $groups = $this->User->Group->find('list');
    $this->set(compact('groups'));
}
/**
* delete method
*
* @param string $id
* @return void
*/
public function delete($id = null) {
    if (!$this->request->is('post')) {
        throw new MethodNotAllowedException();
    }
    $this->User->id = $id;
    if (!$this->User->exists()) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid user'));
    }
    if ($this->User->delete()) {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('User deleted'));
        $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
    }
    $this->Session->setFlash(__('User was not deleted'));
    $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
}


public function login() {
    if ($this->Session->read('Auth.User')) {
        $this->Session->setFlash('You are logged in!');
        return $this->redirect('/');
    }
}

public function logout() {
   $this->Session->setFlash('Good-Bye');
   $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
}
}
```

Comment: Hi what is the issue in login ?

Comment: The login function didn't work. When I hit the Login button, the page just reload. It didn't redirect on what loginRedirect function should be.

Comment: Where should it redirect After login ?

Comment: in this  $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array(
      'controller' => 'users',
      'action' => 'add'
    );

I post my app controller above.

Answer (score 0):

Clean your code in login() action/method , and use

```
 public function login() {

 if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if ($this->Auth->login()) {
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
            // Prior to 2.3 use `return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());`
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Username or password is incorrect'), 'default', array(), 'auth');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I received an error. Fatal error: Call to undefined method AuthComponent::redirectUrl()

Comment: May be some issue regarding to Version , Can you use -> `return $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'posts','action' => 'add'));
`

Comment: Anyways its just a constant Without any functionality so you can set `return $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'posts','action' => 'add'));` without any issue.

Comment: Do you think the ACL will not affect after this? Because I used ACL before, CakePHP 1.3 is my version before. And now, I tried in CakePHP 2.0.0 but it didn't work.

Comment: First use this and tell what happens : `return $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'posts','action' => 'add'));`

Comment: That will work. I tried it. But what if the user is another role?

Comment: @nosnevetzy , hi , can you send me your source code WITH database file? So that I can figure out what is the issue! My email is there on my Profile page ! Thanks